# Android Google Assistant call action

Tags: android, actions-on-google, google-assist-api, app-actions

I'm working on an app that need to handle Call actions from the Google Assistant.

I've managed to implement the Call action (actions.intent.CREATE_CALL) and make it work.

Sentences that are working (My app is starting and I receive the right intent):

- "Call {Name} on {App name}"
- "**Audio** Call {Name} on {App name}"
- "**Video** Call {Name} on {App name}"

But, what I want to achieve is to add a new **entity-set** to handle different call formats.
For example:

- "***Private*** Call {Name} on {App name}"

  ```
   <parameter name="call.callFormat">
       <entity-set-reference entitySetId="entityCallFormat"/>
   </parameter>

   <entity-set entitySetId="entityCallFormat">
       <entity identifier="PRIVATE_FORMAT" name="private"/>
   </entity-set>
  ```

Unfortunately is not working, when I pronounce the sentence "***Private*** Call {Name} on {App name}", the action is handled by the default Contact/Phone app for calling that person.

I'm doing something wrong? Or what I want to achieve is not possible by using Built-in intents.

Edit: After uninstalling and installing the app (without changes) the initial sentence "Call {Name} on {App name}" is not working anymore, (Only from Actions Tool). Also "Open {App name}" not working anymore.

Comment: how you able to make sentences work, as I am trying it but not succeed in it as it is working using Actions Tool but not with voice command. I am following https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/reference/built-in-intents/communications/create-call .

Answer (score 1):

The [actions.intent.CREATE_CALL](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/reference/built-in-intents/communications/create-call) built-in intent is currently in beta and only supports invocation via a preview created from the App Actions test tool. Until it leaves beta, the built-in intent may behave unreliably when invoked directly from Google Assistant.

Can you please clarify whether you were using Assistant or the test tool, when you attempted to use the inline `entity-set`?

Comment: I was using both (Assistant and the Test tool). With the Test tool, as always, everything was working fine, but with the Assistant it not.

Comment: The built-in intent is currently working as intended then; once it leaves its beta state, your implementation should work from Assistant.

Comment: An update: the [actions.intent.CREATE_CALL](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/reference/built-in-intents/communications/create-call) built-in intent has left beta and is available to both the App Actions test tool and Google Assistant, for the `en-US` locale. Please try your implementation again.